# Using Physical Disks as OS drive in HyperV

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm trying to figure out how to have a VM boot from a Physical Disk. All tutorials and information I've seen when adding a physical drive to a VM only talks about adding the disk as a secondary drive or turning an disk that already has an OS installed on it into a VM inside Hyper-V. What I'm after is a way of telling Hyper-V to treat the physical disk as the main OS drive for the VM. I was able to do this easily in Virtualbox but powers that be (above me) have told me I need to use Hyper-V instead.

Is it possible to tell Hyper-V to install a VM to a physical drive and if so, could you point in me in the right direction?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  There aren't any benefits and you lose the benefits of it being in a VM.

Comment: It's used in an environment where multiple installs (15 at a time) of different Windows ISOs need to be performed at the same time. It's a method that's worked well for us so far but I've been asked to move this to Hyper-V